# getting the error "Invalid DES key size. Key must be exactly 8 bytes long" while encrypting message in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, aes

I have the below java code to encode a string with a pass key

```
     public static String encrypt(String message, String passkey) throws Exception {
     final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
     final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(passkey.getBytes("utf-8"));
     final byte[] keyBytes = ( byte[])resizeArray(digestOfPassword, 24);
     for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
         keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
     }

     final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
     final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
     final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

     final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
     final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);

     String encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherText);         
     return encryptedString;
 }
```

Now I converted the same code into python(Python 2.7), and I tried as below.

```
     def encrypt(message, passkey):
        hash_object = hashlib.sha1(passkey.encode("utf-8"))
        digested_passkey = hash_object.digest() //hashing
        key24 = "{: <24}".format(digested_passkey) // for resizing the   byte array to size 24  
        import pyDes
        des = pyDes.des(key24);(at this line I m getting the error "Invalid DES key size. Key must be exactly 8 bytes long".
        message = message.encode('utf-8')
        message = message + (16 - len(message) % 16) * chr(16 - len(message) % 16)  // this is for padding
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(des, AES.MODE_CBC, iv) 
        return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(message))
```

At the line des = pyDes.des(key24), I am getting the error "Invalid DES key size. Key must be exactly 8 bytes long."

The passkey that I sent as parameter is     "f!16*hw$sda66"
Can anyone please let me know if there is anything wrong with the line 
des = pyDes.des(key24)

Comment: I hope you know "DESede" is Triple DES. That's why the key in the Java version is 24 bytes.

Comment: @rustyx, yes I need to use Triple DES. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you are getting this error is because the Class initialisation method is expecting the key to be exactly 8, if it's anything else it raises the error you are seeing, this is the **init** of the class you are calling from pyDes:

```
# Initialisation
def __init__(self, key, mode=ECB, IV=None, pad=None, padmode=PAD_NORMAL):
    # Sanity checking of arguments.
    if len(key) != 8:
        raise ValueError("Invalid DES key size. Key must be exactly 8 bytes long.")
```

If you do this for debugging:

```
def encrypt(message, passkey):
hash_object = hashlib.sha1(passkey.encode("utf-8"))
digested_passkey = hash_object.digest() //hashing
key24 = "{: <24}".format(digested_passkey)
print len(key24)
```

You will see the length of the key is 24, which is why I think it is not being accepted.

I might be wrong but at a quick glance that looks like the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :), I will see if I can remove that statement

Comment: No problem, if you need more assistance let me know.